# Log4j2 programmatic modifying current configuration, synchronizing addAppender and addLogger

Tags: log4j2

I want to modify log4j2 configuration after init (which is done with log4j2.xml file), meaning during runtime, and in official docs it says (point 2 in below snippet) that "Modification to the running configuration requires that all the methods being called (addAppender and addLogger) be synchronized."

I don't understand if they meant only those two calls or other calls as well, or if I as a user will need to synchronize the methods, and reason for it is that addLogger() is already Synchronized (implemented in AbstractConfiguration) and addLogger is using a ConcurrentHashMap (for loggerConfigs var), so I see no reason why I need to synchronize these calls.

P.S

I need runtime modification partly for user configuration of messages to be sent to syslog (with host,facility,port of their choice), so I'm adding syslog appenders in runtime. I don't see any other way then programmatic changes.

[image]